# Use Bullet in my c++ project in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, collision-detection, bulletphysics

I want to use the Bullet library only for collision detection between two convex hulls. My problem is how to link the library in my project and specify that in the *CMakeLists.txt*.

I don't really understand how to install the Bullet library. I cloned the [repo](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) in a folder, created a build folder, compiled it with cmake and installed it. I tried to link the library to my project by adding in the *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
find_package( Bullet REQUIRED )
include_directories(${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR} )

LINK_LIBRARIES(
 BulletDynamics BulletCollision
)
```

This works fine also when I add the headers in my projects. But when I use some function of the Bullet library, I get the following compilation error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libBulletDynamics.a(btTypedConstraint.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I tried to google it in order to resolve the problem but I was not able to resolve it (My knowledge of CMake and this stuff is very basic). 
Also I found somewhere that the library should be included in the project and then compiled, so my project structure is this one:

```
/trunk 
    CMakeLists.txt
    Findmy_project.cmake
    /bin
    /build
    /src
       /examples
          CMakeLists.txt
          test.cpp
       my_algorithm.cpp
       my_algorithm.h
       CMakeLists.txt
```

where `test.cpp` is a source file that uses a class defined in `my_algorithm.h`, but I have no idea how to link the Bullet library to the project now.

So my question is in summary: How do I have to link, and where to install, the Bullet library to use it in my c++ project?

Comment: `Also I found somewhere ...` - this starts *another* problem, which correlates a little with the first one(about error in linking with Bullet's library). It is better to have **one question post per problem**, so you may collect the best answers for every of them.

Comment: my question is just one, I just presented two "paths" I tried to follow, I just want to use the library, whatever solution is fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile Bullet library with `-fPIC`, as linker's error message says.

Either configure this library with CMake variable [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) set:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on <source-dir>
```

or with CMake variable [CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE.html) set:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=on <source-dir>
```

The first way you will get shared libraries, which always have `-fPIC` flag enabled, the second way you will compile libraries statically, but with given flag explicitely set.

Comment: Thanks, It works with cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on <source-dir>